# What size card sleeves should I buy for Penny Arcade - Gamers vs. Evil?

Tags: penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil

Just picked up [Penny Arcade The Game: Gamers vs. Evil](http://www.cryptozoic.com/games/penny-arcade-game-gamers-vs-evil).

I like sleeving my card games.  What size sleeves should I get for these?

(I just compared them vs. Dominion, and they're slightly shorter and slightly wider, but I don't know if that's a standard size or what.)

Answer (score 1):

On the producer site (Fantasy Flight Games) you will see that you can use their 2 1/2" x 3 1/2" (63.5 x 88 MM) card sleeves.

On [this link](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=88&esem=2) you can see that you can use 3 packs of their Standard Card Game Sleeves (grey color packs) and on [this page](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=86&esem=2&esum=123) you will see the card sleeves sold by them (the last product from the list).

Another card sleeves producer is Mayday Games. I think that their corresponding card sleeves are named "Card Game Sleeves" (2 1/2" x 3 1/2" (63.5 x 88 MM)) - green pack. I am pretty sure but you can visit their site. They have a pdf file where you can search for your game and see what kind of sleeves you need. IMPORTANT: Today I see that their site is consider by google as threat because they find malicious software, so I think is not a good idea to enter wright now on their page.

Also you can search for [ultra pro sleeves](http://www.ultrapro.com/index.php?cPath=64_68) but i don't know exactly what kind you should search for.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but is unfortunately for the wrong game! This game from Fantasy Flight: http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite.asp?eidm=88&enmi=Penny%20Arcade:%20The%20Card%20Game is different from this game from Cryptozoic: http://www.cryptozoic.com/games/penny-arcade-game-gamers-vs-evil

Comment: Though I finally found a ruler and actually measured the cards. It appears they happen to be the same size (by my measurements, 63mm x 88.5mm, which is hopefully close enough).